# Type on a Path Not Working

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

I'm trying to use the type on a path tool, and I've never had this problem before. I'm using the rainbow option as usual, but it is typing within the path not on top of it, and sideways. The other settings are working the same, but those are not what I'm looking for. Is there a weird setting that I changed by accident?

[image]

Comment: Use the [Type on a Path tool](https://imgur.com/FuHPQgC), not the Vertical Type on a Path tool

Comment: ermm... that's *exactly* what my answer reads Billy.. no clue why you feel it's necessary to add a comment, at a later time,  that merely duplicates an *already provided* answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 type on a path tools.. horizontal and vertical.

It looks like you may have inadvertently used the **Vertical Type on a Path Tool** rather than the more traditional **Type on a Path Tool** (which is for horizontal type).